# display both occupied and empty beds mySQL

Tags: mysql

Im having a crisis with this query of mine:

```
SELECT
    `tbl_beds`.`Bed_No`
    , `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_In`
    , `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_Out`
FROM
    `csbdb2`.`tbl_bedrest`
    INNER JOIN `csbdb2`.`tbl_beds` 
        ON (`tbl_bedrest`.`Bed_ID` = `tbl_beds`.`Bed_ID`)
WHERE 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN `tbl_bedrest`.time_in AND `tbl_bedrest`.time_out
    GROUP BY `tbl_beds`.`Bed_No`
```

What im looking for is to get All of the beds and display them even if they are occupied or not within the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| bed_id    | time_in             | time_out            |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| BED000001 |                null |                null |
| BED000002 | 2016-01-14 09:00:00 | 2016-01-14 15:00:00 |
| BED000003 | 2016-01-14 06:00:00 | 2016-01-14 09:00:00 |
| BED000004 | 2016-01-14 09:55:07 | 2016-01-14 09:51:45 |
| BED000005 | 2016-01-14 10:00:18 | 2016-01-14 09:57:54 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here are my tables:

tbl_Beds

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Bed_ID   | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Bed_No   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Building | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

tbl_bedrest

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BedRest_ID | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Time_In    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Time_Out   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Case_ID    | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Bed_ID     | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN, change the order in which the tables are referenced and move the `BETWEEN ...` condition into the `ON` clause. This should work.

```
SELECT
    `tbl_beds`.`Bed_No`
    , `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_In`
    , `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_Out`
FROM
    `csbdb2`.`tbl_beds` 
    LEFT JOIN `csbdb2`.`tbl_bedrest`
        ON (`tbl_bedrest`.`Bed_ID` = `tbl_beds`.`Bed_ID` AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN `tbl_bedrest`.time_in AND `tbl_bedrest`.time_out)
    GROUP BY `tbl_beds`.`Bed_No`
```

A LEFT JOIN will produce results for the left table even if no matching rows are found in the right table.

Comment: it works! I just had to remove the `WHERE` coz i was getting an error because of it. thanks!

Comment: This query must return an indeterminate result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an approach like this:

```
SELECT
`tbl_beds`.`Bed_No`
, `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_In`
, `tbl_bedrest`.`Time_Out`
, (case when (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN `tbl_bedrest`.time_in AND `tbl_bedrest`.time_out=
    THEN 
        'occupied'
    ELSE
        'free'
    END) as `state`
FROM
    `csbdb2`.`tbl_bedrest`
    INNER JOIN `csbdb2`.`tbl_beds` 
        ON (`tbl_bedrest`.`Bed_ID` = `tbl_beds`.`Bed_ID`)
```

Comment: got an error, and I had never used CASE before. would be nice if you could point the mistake? 

syntax to use near 'THEN 
        'occupied'
    ELSE
        'free'
    END) as `state`
FROM
    `c' at line 6

Comment: this Query won't work if there is a row in tbl_Beds with no corresponding entry in tbl_bedrest. You have to use a LEFT JOIN like in my solution.

Comment: so this query wont work if tbl_bedrest is empty right?

Comment: it won't work if tbl_bedrest is empty or if a specific row in tbl_beds has no entry in tbl_bedrest.